# Java app with embedded DERBY DB

Tags: java, derby

I am trying for a while to make executable JAVA application having embedded DB (derby DB), but facing some problems, and need your valuable help.

Namely, I am using Eclipse as environment.
I export Java app to RUNNABLE JAR file, and it works fine on my desktop machine.

The idea is to make EXE doubleclick icon and send it to another machine which have no JAVA background/environment....so point is to send it to another user who will just get exe file, double click it and work with it.

The DB is not only readable, since application is inserting data in tables.
So, it works fine on my machine, but when I send the same JAR file to another machine, I get error:
"Schema TEST does not exist"
I can see application but without any data, like there is no connection with DB. So, it is useless.

Even I use JSmooth, Install4j.... to convert JAR to exe file, I get the same error.
So, first I have to make JAR file working on another machine.

Seems to me, I am doing something wrong with DB files.

Please let me know what info u need more from my side, and let me know how I can do this.

Comment: where do you store your db data? where do you put db data files?

Answer (score 2):

If the application intends to read AND WRITE data when it is running, then it can't be entirely contained in a JAR file, because you can't put an updatable Derby database in a JAR file. You'll need to have some "installation procedure", perhaps some logic that you run the first time your application is double-clicked by the user, that (a) finds a suitable location for the Derby database on the user's machine, (b) creates the database and defines all the tables, views, etc, (c) loads any initial data.

Then, on subsequent runs of the application, it will be able to re-open the database and continue using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what is the point of embedded DB if i need to create all on users machine? Point is that user should not know about DB at all.

When I put this: con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true;user=app;password=app");

the error I get is:

Table/View "PREMIER' does not exist.

I do not understand it, since every time application is double-clicked, it checks if table exist, and in case it does not, it creates.

It seems like it is lost in JAR file, because it works fine from eclipse.

Comment: "jdbc:derby:myDB;create=true" tells Derby "look in the folder 'myDB', relative to your current working directory, for the database files. If they aren't there, go ahead and quietly create a brand new empty database". So given the behavior you are seeing, it seems like your application is getting a new temporary working directory each time it is double-clicked. If you want your data to persist from run to run, you need to decide on a location on disk to store that data, and you need to specify *that* location in your connection URL.